# setitimer, SIGALRM & multithread process (linux, c)

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, profiling, signals

I want to use `setitimer()` (or less probable, the `alarm()`) in multithreaded process in linux 2.6+ with NPTL-enabled libc. Which thread will receive `sigalarm (SIGALRM)` from kernel?

Thanks.

2014-04 update: How should I set the `setitimer()` in multithreaded program, if I want to write a profiling utility like gperftools's cpuprofile; but in my tool I want to support both dynamically linked programs (so it is possible to inject my own library to init profiling) and statically linked programs (without the possibility of doing ^^^^^^).

My current profiling tool works with setting `setitimer` just after `fork()` and before `exec()`, and it also uses `ptrace` to get control over the target program and to hijack SIGPROF/SIGVPROF/SIGALRM generated by the `setitimer`. I have no exact idea how it works with multithreaded programs.

Comment: is the same true for freebsd and solaris?

Answer (score 15):

From [signal(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal) man page:

> A process-directed signal may be
>   delivered to any one of the threads
>   that does not currently have the
>   signal blocked. If more than one of
>   the threads has the signal unblocked,
>   then the kernel chooses an arbitrary
>   thread to which to deliver the signal.

Now, [alarm(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm) man page says that:

> alarm() arranges for a SIGALRM signal
>   to be delivered to the process in
>   seconds seconds.

So, the signal is delivered to a *process* (a signal might be directed at certain thread too) and thus you do not know which of the threads will receive it.

The same with [setitimer(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer):

> When any timer expires, a signal is
>   sent to the process, and the timer
>   (potentially) restarts.

You could block `SIGALARM` in all your threads except one, then you could be certain that it will be delivered to that only thread. Assuming you are using pthreads, you can block signals with [pthread_sigmask()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_sigmask).

Comment: It's the same for all signals.

Comment: @nos Basically, but you can deliver signals straight to certain thread with for instance `pthread_kill()`

Comment: Also, signals raised from hardware exception are delivered to the thread

Answer (score 6):

There was interesting topic in LKML in 2010 https://lkml.org/lkml/2010/4/11/81: "*setitimer vs. threads: SIGALRM returned to which thread? (process master or individual child)*" by Frantisek Rysanek ([cz](http://frantisek.rysanek.sweb.cz/)). Author says that `setitimer` used per-thread signals at least in times before Fedora 5:

> ... `setitimer()` had per-thread granularity.  It used to deliver a `SIGALRM` from the timer to the particular thread  that called `setitimer()`.

But in more recent Fedoras the behavior was changed (*"man pthreads", ..."Threads do not share interval timers (fixed in kernel 2.6.12)."*)

In the topic, Andi Kleen (Intel) [recommends to switch to](https://lkml.org/lkml/2010/4/11/81) "*POSIX timers ([`timer_create`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/timer_create.html))*"; and in [ML thread](https://lkml.org/lkml/2010/4/11/92) Davide Libenzi suggests use of `timerfd` (timerfd_create, timerfd_settime) on non-ancient Linuxes.

Comment: Googled with "`setitimer` thread process". Other interesting pages: [Solaris 9](http://www.shrubbery.net/solaris9ab/SUNWdev/MTP/p34.html) "When the interval timer expired, either SIGVTALRM or SIGPROF, as appropriate, was sent to the LWP that owned the interval timer."; [Redhat bug 142790 "setitimer CPU timers should be per-process, not per thread", 2004](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=142790) "setitimer operates on individual threads, even under NPTL. POSIX says it should be process-wide." Send hate mails to POSIX and Roland McGrath  ("My changes are in Linus's tree now...2.6.12")

Comment: Google-perftools (gperftools) with cpuprofile should have same problems with `setitimer`: https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/ "*OS X issue: in multithreaded programs, it seems that OS X often delivers the profiling signal (from sigitimer()) to the main thread, even when it's sleeping, rather than spawned threads that are doing actual work*"; https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gperftools/+/8e188310f7d8732d81b7b04f193f89964b7af6c5/src/profiler.cc - "*TODO: Detect whether or not setitimer() applies to all threads in the process.*"

Comment: HPUX has additional interval timers with well-defined behavior for threads: http://www.polarhome.com/service/man/generic.php?qf=setitimer&type=2&of=HP-UX&sf=2 *"In  addition... HP-UX provides the following three per-thread interval timers for threads, ... signal is delivered to the thread..."*

Comment: timer_create on Linux allows specifying the thread id to receive the signal. I wonder if there's a POSIX conformant way to do it, though I really only care about having a timer-thread local, not about installing a timer on one thread to signal another.

Answer (score 0):

I've read many posts but I haven't found how the signals work exactly. I usually use pause() to wait for a signal. But that doesn't work because SIGALARM can't be excluded and pause() doesn't return a signal. That's why it only works with sigwait. After a few tries I came up with this solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>//"-lpthread" linker option needed

pthread_t thr1;

//wait for all, except SIGALRM
int sigwaitexcludealarm()
{   sigset_t set;
    sigfillset(&set);
    sigdelset(&set,SIGALRM);
    int sig=0;
    sigwait(&set,&sig);
    return sig;
}

//simple one shot timer
void dotimer(int sig)
{   printf("ALARM!\n");
    struct itimerval timerval;
    timerval.it_value.tv_sec=0;
    timerval.it_value.tv_usec=500000;//0,5 sec
    timerval.it_interval.tv_sec=0;
    timerval.it_interval.tv_usec=0;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timerval, NULL);
}

//timer thread worker
void* timer_run(void* p)
{   printf("thread start\n");
    signal(SIGALRM, dotimer);
    dotimer(0);
    sigwaitexcludealarm();
    printf("thread finished\n");
}

//do shutdown
void doeshutdown(int sig)
{   pthread_kill(thr1,sig);
    pthread_join(thr1,NULL);
    printf("shutdown done\n");
}

//signal handler, needed but never called
void donop(int sig)
{   return;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   printf("main start\n");
    pthread_create(&thr1,NULL,timer_run,NULL);
    //connecting signals to this process
    signal(SIGINT, donop);
    signal(SIGTERM, donop);
    signal(SIGKILL, donop);
    doeshutdown(sigwaitexcludealarm());
    printf("main exit\n");
    return 0;
}
```