# sigwait not behaving as expected

Tags: python, signals

**Unix only**

```
from threading import Thread
from signal import signal, alarm, sigwait, SIGALRM


class Check(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        signal(SIGALRM, Check.handler)

    @staticmethod
    def handler(*_):
        print("Hello")

    def run(self):
        for _ in range(5):
            alarm(1)
            print("Waiting...")
            sigwait((SIGALRM,))
            print("done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    (check := Check()).start()
    check.join()
```

**Expected behaviour:**

I expect the following output to be repeated 5 times:

```
Waiting...
Hello
done
```

However, "done" is never printed because the runtime is "blocking" on *sigwait()*

"Hello" is printed. Therefore I know that the signal handler has been invoked.

If SIGALARM has been signalled (via *alarm()*) and handled, why does *sigwait()* not return?

**Platform:**

```
macOS 14.2.1
Python 3.12.1
```

**EDIT to include call to pthread_sigmask**

```
from threading import Thread
from signal import signal, alarm, sigwait, pthread_sigmask, SIGALRM, SIG_BLOCK


class Check(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        signal(SIGALRM, self.handler)

    def handler(self, *_):
        print("Hello")

    def run(self):
        mask = SIGALRM,
        pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, mask)
        
        for _ in range(5):
            alarm(1)
            print("Waiting...")
            sigwait(mask)
            print("done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    (check := Check()).start()
    check.join()
```

**Behaviour is identical to original code**

Comment: By the looks of it, you'd need [`pthread_sigmask`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html) to be able to use blocked signals (and by extension `sigwait`) in the first place...

Comment: @AKX I tried that but couldn't get it to behave as needed. I'll add that attempt to the question

Comment: Well, I suspect your signal gets handled by your handler, so it's no longer pending. And yes, I know that if you don't set a handler for `SIGALRM`, it'll terminate the target process. I'd wager `sigwait` is only meant for things like `SIGUSR1`.

Comment: @AKX There are multiple resources that show sigwait() being used for arbitrary signals. See my "answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2586964/51685) helped clear things up some.

Since `signal()` can, for sanity reasons, only be called from the main thread in Python ("The effects of `signal()` in a multithreaded process are unspecified", says the Linux manpage for `signal()`), in order to receive a signal in another thread you'll have to use synchronous signals (unless you arrange for your main-thread-configured `signal` to e.g. set a `threading.Event`).

Since the default action for `SIGALRM` is to terminate the process, you'll have to arrange for it not to be received on the main thread at all in order to receive it on another thread, by way of `pthread_sigmask(SIG_IGN, ...)` there, and then set it to blocking mode on the signal receiver thread. (Other threads spawned from that main thread will inherit the sigmask otherwise.)

This uses a `threading.Event()` to let the main thread know the receiver received a thing.

```
import signal
import threading

mask = (signal.SIGALRM,)
ev = threading.Event()


class SignalReceiver(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        signal.pthread_sigmask(signal.SIG_BLOCK, mask)
        while True:
            signal.sigwait(mask)
            print("Got signal")
            ev.set()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SignalReceiver(daemon=True).start()
    signal.pthread_sigmask(signal.SIG_IGN, mask)

    for _ in range(3):
        signal.alarm(1)
        print("Waiting...")
        ev.wait()
        ev.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a full answer because I can't explain why *sigwait* doesn't behave as I'd expect in a threaded context. However, here's what I've determined empirically.

Consider this main program:

```
from signal import sigwait, SIGALRM, alarm
from time import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = time()
    alarm(1)
    sigwait((SIGALRM,))
    b = time()
    print(round(b-a, 2))
```

The output of this is:

```
1.01
```

And that's what I expect - i.e., a pause of ~1s

Now consider this:

```
from threading import Thread
from signal import sigwait, SIGALRM, alarm
from time import time

class SigTest(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def run(self):
        a = time()
        alarm(1)
        sigwait((SIGALRM,))
        b = time()
        print(round(b-a, 2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    (t := SigTest()).start()
    t.join()
```

When I run this, the python executable terminates due to the fact that the alarm is neither caught nor in any other way observed. So the output, on my system, is:

```
zsh: alarm      /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/CtrlZ/Python/Jan08.py
```

If I enhance this code by adding:

```
pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, (SIGALRM,))
```

...to the *run()* function override, the behaviour is the same - i.e., python terminates due to SIGALRM not being observed.

Now let's take this further and introduce a signal handler:

```
from threading import Thread
from signal import signal, sigwait, SIGALRM, SIG_BLOCK, alarm, pthread_sigmask
from time import time

class SigTest(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        signal(SIGALRM, SigTest.handler)
    @staticmethod
    def handler(signum, _):
        print(f"Signal {signum} handled")
    def run(self):
        mask = SIGALRM,
        # note that the behaviour does not change...
        # ...if pthread_sigmask is called in this way
        #pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, mask)
        a = time()
        alarm(1)
        sigwait(mask)
        b = time()
        print(round(b-a, 2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    (t := SigTest()).start()
    t.join()
```

The output of this is:

```
Signal 14 handled
```

However, the program then blocks *ad infinitum*

In summary therefore, it seems that signal handling in threads is something that I do not fully understand.

If anyone could give a full explanation of this behaviour I would be forever grateful